# Would like to insert a pdf link on a jpg photo

Tags: pdf, photos

I am wanting to insert a link to a pdf file on a jpg photo. Strange, I know, but I sell gemstones online, and think that being able to open a document showing the actual size of the stone on the items would be very helpful to the potential customer, and would cut down on returns by viewing true size.  I realize that i could include this link in the product description,  but i want to make this way a hallmark of our "truth in advertising " .  Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Short answer: You can't.insert a link **into** a jpeg image in an way that it can be clicked. Longer answer: You **can** make the jpeg image clickable and so open a pdf if you want, but that needs to be programmed on your website and is therefore off topic on [su].

Comment: If you mean an actual clickable link - not possible. If it was on a website you could incorporate that in the page code. Otherwise the only thing you could do was make it legible & have them type it into a browser. Embedding a [QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) might be more feasible. Also, I would be extremely wary of trying to represent anything at "actual size" on a computer. Few people have a computer set up to view absolute sizes. If you're talking weeny stuff like diamonds… there is great margin for error… "But it looks like 17 carat on my screen!!!" ;)

Comment: My gosh, that was super fast and I truly appreciate your answers.  You just saved me hours and hours of wasted time.  I wish I could return the kindness.  Mackie

Comment: So, it seems like just  posting a printable 8x11" pdf with a disclaimer for all stone shapes and sizes would be the only safe and accurate way to  get this to customers w

Comment: Maybe so - assuming your market uses US paper sizes. Most of the world doesn't… yet another fly in the ointment ;)